# convert 100 ticks per second to milliseconds

Tags: arithmetic, unit-of-measure

I used `sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)` to get time resolution on my pc. I got back 100 ticks per second. How do I convert that to milliseconds? I know there 1000 milliseconds in 1 second but I feel like its more complicated that since I need to account for ticks. 100t/1s 1s/1000ms =  .100 milliseconds doesnt seem right.

Comment: This would be more suitable for StackOverflow, however this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/q/386341/20193105

Comment: The math is undeniable. You get $100$ ticks equals $1000$ ms which is $10$ ms / tick.

Comment: For your purpose, you've written the conversion upside-down:  you want $$ \frac{1 \ \text{sec.}}{100 \ \text{tick}} \ · \ \frac{1000 \ \text{msec.}}{1 \ \text{sec.}} \ \ = \ \  \frac{1000}{100} \ \frac{\text{msec.}}{\text{tick}} \ \ , \ $$ with units "cancelling" like numbers do.

Answer (score 1):

So you have
$$
100 \frac{\text{ticks}}{\text{sec}}
 = 100 \frac{\text{ticks}}{\text{sec}} \times 1,000 \frac{\text{sec}}{\text{msec}}
 = 100,000 \frac{\text{ticks}}{\text{msec}}
$$